# How do you specify range to end of list?

Tags: groovy

Consider the following statement:

process.text.readLines[3..<-1]

It seems like it should work. Essentially, strip off the first two elements of the array. However, the range operator is confused by the ending -1, since its less than -1. You can easily solve this problem by storing the array as a variable and replacing -1 with size() but that requires an extra line and the definition of a variable. Any other ideas how to express this easily?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you could do:

```
process.text.readLines()[ 2..-1 ]
```

or:

```
process.text.readLines().drop( 2 )
```

Comment: ok so it's a problem with the "<" operator. This seems to generate [2, 1, 0, -1]. Shouldn't 2..<-1 generate [2, 1, 0] then? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3):

This will also do the trick:

```
process.text.readLines().with { it[2..size()-1] }
```

It's longer than simply calling `drop` as suggested above, but it might read a little better depending on the larger context. `with` lets you get around defining a new variable.

Comment: i believe you still need the parentheses on size: `it[ 2..<size() ]`

Comment: Also a good solution. I keep forgetting the value that with() has in avoiding variable declarations.